# Building Android Studio 3.2.1 for Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, build

As of 29 November 2018 i was unable to follow the instructions here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/source.md

to compile Android Studio on Windows for Windows.

I don´t know if i am following the instructions wrongly. For me the instructions do not work.

I would like to know if you could follow them and manage it to compile Android Studio on your Windows 10 machine? If so, i would like to know how you have done this.

Comment: What do you mean by "was unable to follow instructions"? On which step did you run into problems?

Comment: I got stuck on several steps. I tried by myself to find a workaround but i do not know if i am doing the right thing. The first time i got stuck was installing "repo" on windows. My workaround was to use cygwin to use repo. I do not know if it is the way to go. With the help of cygwin i was able to get the sources. Is is ment to be done like this?